# How do I set up SDL2 on VSCode on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, sdl, sdl-2

How do I set up SDL2 on VSCode Linux (Ubuntu)?

I can't find any tutorials on Linux SDL2 on VS Code

Comment: How would you do it without VSC? With VSC it is the same. VSC is just an EDITOR

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is just an editor, so install SDL2 the same way as usual in Ubuntu. To install everything necessary to build programs that use SDL in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libsdl2-2.0 install libsdl2-dev
```